# Selenium RC : How to handle drop down list while automating?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, selenium2

How to handle  the drop down by using  selenium RC. While I am automating Gmail  registration page the birthday section giving error

Answer (score 1):

You need to show us:

- HTML code
- Your code
- Your error message

Having said that, I assume you are talking about Month dropdown list from Gmail registration?

From what I can see:

- Month dropdown list, you can click to open it by using `span id = "BirthMonth"`
- After this list is expanded, you can get a list of items by using `div class = "goog-menu goog-menu-vertical"`, looking for its child elements `div class = "goog-menuitem"`, each `div class = "goog-menuitem"` represents a month respectively.

Comment: Ohk.... I am just adding the same